# How to use reduce/lambda function on matrices and vectors in python?

Tags: python, lambda, functional-programming, reduce

I am trying to write the following function using functional programming.

```
def mv(A,X,n):
    Y = [0]*n
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            Y[i] += A[i][j] * X[j]
    return Y
```

Can the reduce function multiply a vector with a matrix? Because that is what I am trying to do here. I am trying to multiply the matrix `A` with the vector `X` but receive an error. The error is:

> TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable

```
def mv(A,X,n):
    return list(map(sum,lambda x, y: x*y(A, X)))
```

To the input:

```
A = [[1,2],[3,4]]
X = [1,2]
n = 2
print(mv(A,X,n))
```

The output should be:

```
[5,11]
```

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable

Comment: As expected. Second argument to `map` is an iterable not function so you have to pass your list instead of `lambda`

Comment: How about some input and expected output? Obviously, you cannot use a `lambda` here.

Comment: but I would like to multiply the matrix A with vector X first before summing

Comment: Is it possible for you to use `numpy`?

Comment: but then would I not have to assume that the input given to me was a numpy matrix? I currently don't want to make any assumptions about the input and want to be able to handle an arbitrary input.

Comment: @ce1 then cast it as a numpy array inside the function. If the input is an array it won't change anything, if it's not, it'll convert it to an array. Just like `list([3, 4, 5]) == [3, 4, 5]`. What is `y(A, x)` supposed to be doing here??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick and dirty solution using list-comprehensions, if you want to stick with functional constructs (comprehensions being favored in Python over `map` and `filter`):

```
import operator as op
x = [[1],[2],[3]] # Notice the dimensions!
A = [[1,1,1],
     [2,2,2],
     [3,3,3]]

def matrix_mult(A, X):
    return [
        [sum(map(op.mul, row, col)) for col in zip(*X)]
        for row in A
    ]
```

To see in action:

```
In [17]: A
Out[17]: [[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]]

In [18]: x
Out[18]: [[1], [2], [3]]

In [19]: matrix_mult(A, x)
Out[19]: [[6], [12], [18]]
```

Comment: @splash58 sorry, what?

Comment: The code on eval looks easier, does not need change structure of vector and result. But i don't use python, so may don't know why you choose another way

Comment: @splash58 yes, but you said you want to be *general*. I am assuming your arrays and matrices have some concept of *dimension*. Again, I'm not sure what you are trying to do here. If this is only an exercise, then do whatever you want. Note, the implementation I showed you can multiply *any* two matrix-like objects, and doesn't assume the second argument is a sequence representing a one-dimensional vector.

Comment: @splash58 if you **actually** need to use vector-multiplication then I suggest you use `numpy`/`scipy`, because these implementations will be woefully inadequate on production-level data.

Comment: That is not my question :) I just try to understand logic of python, and code on eval is my trying to solve.  I don't know what OP want. I asked you  just - Does I don't take into account some points, writting my code simpler. Or in other words - it's easier but maybe wrong ?

Comment: @splash58 It simply doesn't take into account several things regarding matrix multiplications. It assumes that your second argument is a "vector" not a matrix, and it is of a particular shape (one that goes against the conventions of matrix multiplication). So, consider `X, Y = [[1,2],[3,4]], [[2, 0],[1,2]]` then try `matrix_mult(X,Y)` and you'll see `[[4, 4], [10, 8]]`, however, `matrix_mult1(X,Y)` will throw an error... Note, the `matrix_mult` implementation is bare-bones, and does no dimension checking, which it probably should. But if the input is correct, the output will be too.

Comment: @splash58 also, sorry for the confusion, I thought *you* were the OP.

Comment: Of course, I understood question as matrix-vector multiply based on text and name of function `mv`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I have tried your implementation with your inputs and got the error: "TypeError: zip argument #1 must support iteration" . Do you know what the problem could be?

Comment: @ce1 no, the code posted works exactly as shown. That is the output of a live interpreter session. Can you post exactly what you did, including the error message?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga sorry that was my mistake. It works correctly, thank you. One thing, could you please explain what the zip(*X) is doing?

Comment: @ce1 that's transposing the list. It yields columns. Try something like `list(zip(*A))`